# Re-posting this....php edit for Cufon font replacement

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, cufon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php edit for Cufon font replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253581/php-edit-for-cufon-font-replacement)

I am reposting this due to the confusion and misconceptions of the previous post. I am trying to change the color of the menu items on my **WORDPRESS** website with no luck. I contacted the themes creator and he said to make the changes in the below code. **I DONT SEE WHERE TO DO THIS THOUGH!!!** There is a custom color changer in the wordpress theme setting but it does not have the ability to change menu or title (post or page) colors. (and i need to do both ) please help....***note that changing the css also has availed nothing***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Cufon font replacement & text shadows
    Cufon.replace('#sidebar .font, #content .post .font, #card-container .font, #frontwidgets h3, #gallery .gal_item .font, #nicepagination .font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#fff 0px 1px' });
    Cufon.replace('#footer .font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#000 0px -1px' });
    Cufon.replace('#content .title-container .font, #mainmenu ul.menu li:not(.current_page_item, .current-menu-parent) a.font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#<?php echo $color->bg['-4']; ?> 0px -1px' });
    Cufon.replace('#mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-item a.font, #mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-parent a.font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: 'none' });

    // Fixing menu hovers as cufon can't seem to handle different div-hover colors
    $('#mainmenu').find('ul.menu').children('li:not(.current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent)').hover(
        function () {
            Cufon.replace($(this).find('a.font'),{ fontFamily: 'Junction', color: '#<?php echo $color->bg['0']; ?>', textShadow: 'none' });
        },
        function () {
            Cufon.replace($(this).find('a.font'),{ fontFamily: 'Junction', color: '#<?php echo $color->fg['-2']; ?>', textShadow: '#<?php echo $color->bg['-4']; ?> 0px -1px' });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Here is the css that i edited...it did nothing but what the heck

```
/* begin ---------------------------------------- menu */
#mainmenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 81px;
    width: 100%;
}
#mainmenu .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
}
#menu-bg {
    width: 990px;
    height: 53px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('images/menu_bg.png') no-repeat;
}
#menu-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background: url('images/menu_left.png') no-repeat;
}
#menu-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background: url('images/menu_right.png') no-repeat;
}
#menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 43px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('images/patern_sharp.png');
    float: left;
    border-top: #000 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 150px;
}
#mainmenu .dropdown_arrow {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 10px;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover .dropdown_arrow, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-menu-item .dropdown_arrow, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-menu-parent .dropdown_arrow {
    top: 21px;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li a {
    color: #fff;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-parent {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 17px 14px 18px 14px;
    margin: -3px 3px 0 3px;
    border-top: #dedede 1px solid;
    border-right: #dedede 1px solid;
    border-left: #dedede 1px solid;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-menu-parent {
    padding-right: 29px;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover {
    padding-bottom: 24px;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    top: 55px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-right: #dedede 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #dedede 1px solid;
    border-left: #dedede 1px solid;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li {
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu li a, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: auto;
}
#mainmenu ul.menu li a:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#stars-left {
    background: url('images/stars.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 60px;
    height: 13px;
    width: 61px;
}
#stars-right {
    background: url('images/stars.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 60px;
    height: 13px;
    width: 61px;
}
/* end ---------------------------------------- menu */
```

Comment: SHOUTING will generally NOT RESULT in better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cufon seems to have it's own CSS-like thing:

```
Cufon.replace('#sidebar .font, #content .post .font, #card-container .font, #frontwidgets h3, #gallery .gal_item .font, #nicepagination .font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#fff 0px 1px' });
Cufon.replace('#footer .font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#000 0px -1px' });
Cufon.replace('#content .title-container .font, #mainmenu ul.menu li:not(.current_page_item, .current-menu-parent) a.font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: '#<?php echo $color->bg['-4']; ?> 0px -1px' });
Cufon.replace('#mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-item a.font, #mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-parent a.font',{ fontFamily: 'Junction', textShadow: 'none' });
```

Try adding your CSS into those functions (I'd try `color`).